# Assembly Program to handle Escape Characters

Tags: assembly

edit 10/2/16 - it's no longer segfaulting but the lowercase characters are not converting - here's what I changed in the lowercase label:

```
lowercase:
        cmp     ax, 'a'                  ; is it a?
        jb      slashprint               ; jump out if it's below a
        cmp     ax, 'z'                  ; is it z?
        ja      slashprint               ; jump out if it's above z
        mov     eax, [esi]               ; move the char to eax to index
        mov     ebx, mappings            ; point to the mappings array
        sub     eax, 97                  ; convert the lower case letter to decimal
        mov     ax, [ebx + eax]          ; indexed addressing done here
        jmp     done
```

I'm working on a program that will allow me to take a string from a user, detect escape sequences and properly output the converted message. I know already that I need to clean up some of the logic inside the subroutine handle_ESC but I'm attempting to test and debug one situation at a time. My issue is that every time I return from the subroutine and go to add the character I modified to the new string stored in edi (on the first line of label L1_cont), I get a segfault. So far I've just been focused on getting it to accept the lower case escape sequences. edit: changed a few things around. Now I'm not segfaulting when typing 2 slashes, but it also doesn't do what I want it to do. It doesn't print anything. Still segfaulting when looking at a lowercase letter from the same line. With the changes I made it should never reach that instruction.

```
%define STDIN 0
%define STDOUT 1
%define SYSCALL_EXIT  1
%define SYSCALL_READ  3
%define SYSCALL_WRITE 4
%define BUFLEN 256


        SECTION .data                   ; initialized data section

msg1:   db "Enter string: "             ; user prompt
len1:   equ $-msg1                      ; length of first message

msg2:   db "Original: "                 ; original string label
len2:   equ $-msg2                      ; length of second message

msg3:   db "Convert:  "                 ; converted string label
len3:   equ $-msg3

msg4:   db 10, "Read error", 10         ; error message
len4:   equ $-msg4

msg5:   db 10, "Error: unknown escape sequence", 10 ; unknown escape error (not sure this works)
len5:   equ $-msg5

msg6:   db 10, "Error: octal value overflow!", 10 ; overflow error
len6:   equ $-msg6

; Declare the array using mappings.
mappings: db 7, 8, -1, -1, -1, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 10, -1, -1, -1, 13, -1, 9, -1, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1


        SECTION .bss                    ; uninitialized data section
buf:    resb BUFLEN                     ; buffer for read
newstr: resb BUFLEN                     ; converted string
rlen:   resb 4                          ; length


        SECTION .text                   ; Code section.
        global  _start                  ; let loader see entry point

_start: nop                             ; Entry point.
start:                                  ; address for gdb

        ; prompt user for input
        ;
        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write function
        mov     ebx, STDOUT             ; Arg1: file descriptor
        mov     ecx, msg1               ; Arg2: addr of message
        mov     edx, len1               ; Arg3: length of message
        int     080h                    ; ask kernel to write

        ; read user input
        ;
        mov     eax, SYSCALL_READ       ; read function
        mov     ebx, STDIN              ; Arg 1: file descriptor
        mov     ecx, buf                ; Arg 2: address of buffer
        mov     edx, BUFLEN             ; Arg 3: buffer length
        mov     [ecx + edx], byte 0     ; null terminate the read buffer
        sub     edx, 1                  ; make sure the buffer length is 1 less than BUFLEN
        int     080h

        ; error check
        ;
        mov     [rlen], eax             ; save length of string read
        cmp     eax, 0                  ; check if any chars read
        jg      read_OK                 ; >0 chars read = OK
        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; ow print error mesg
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, msg4
        mov     edx, len4
        int     080h
        jmp     exit                    ; skip over rest
read_OK:


        ; Loop for iterating over string

L1_init:
        mov     esi, buf                ; point to start of buffer
        mov     edi, newstr             ; point to start of new string
        mov     bx, [mappings]          ; point to the mappings array

L1_top:
        mov     al, [esi]               ; get a character
        inc     esi                     ; point to the next character
        cmp     al, '\'                 ; is current char a backslash?
        je      escapectrl              ; if so, run the subroutine
        jmp     L1_cont                 ; if not, jump to L1_cont and add the char

escapectrl:
        call    handle_ESC              ; run subroutine
        inc     edi
        cmp     [esi], byte 0
        je      L1_end
        jmp     L1_top

L1_cont:
        mov     [edi], al               ; store char in new string
        inc     edi                     ; update dest pointer
        cmp     [esi], byte 0           ; if not null, keep looping
        je      L1_end                  ; end loop if null
        jmp     L1_top                  ; loop if there are more chars



L1_end:


        ; print out user input for feedback
        ;
        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write message
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, msg2
        mov     edx, len2
        int     080h

        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write user input
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, buf
        mov     edx, [rlen]
        int     080h

        ; print out converted string
        ;
        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write message
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, msg3
        mov     edx, len3
        int     080h

        mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write out string
        mov     ebx, STDOUT
        mov     ecx, newstr
        mov     edx, [rlen]
        int     080h


        ; final exit
        ;
exit:   mov     eax, SYSCALL_EXIT       ; exit function
        mov     ebx, 0                  ; exit code, 0=normal
        int     080h                    ; ask kernel to take over

        ; Subroutine begins here.

handle_ESC:

        mov     di, [esi]               ; take a copy of the current char
        inc     esi                     ; point to the next char

        cmp     di, '7'                 ; is it above 7?
        ja      lowercase               ; if so, skip octal check

        cmp     di, '0'                 ; is it below zero?
        jb      lowercase               ; if so, skip octal check

octalinit:
        mov     bl, 0                   ; holds the total for the digit
        mov     cl, 3                   ; count for how many times the loop should run if it's octal
        mov     dh, 8                   ; holds the octal multiple

octalloop:
        mov     ah, [di]                ; store the new char in ah for operations
        sub     ah, 48                  ; convert char to integer
        mul     dl                      ; multiply the octal value by 8
        add     ax, dx                  ; update the total value
        mov     di, [esi]               ; store the next character in di for consideration
        inc     esi                     ; point to the character after that
        cmp     di, '0'                 ; is it below 0?
        jb      lowercase               ; if below, jump out
        cmp     di, '7'                 ; is it above 7?
        ja      lowercase               ; if above, jump out
        dec     cl                      ; count down
        jnz     octalloop               ; loop if needed
        dec     esi                     ; undo the prefetch if no longer looping
        jo      octaloverflow           ; if the overflow flag was set, handle the overflow
        mov     al, bl                  ; stores the finalized value in al
        jmp     done                    ; exit


octaloverflow:
        mov     [edi], byte 32          ; makes the second char blank due to error
        jmp     done                     ; not sure if this part is gonna work right

lowercase:
        cmp     di, 'a'                  ; is it a?
        jb      slashprint               ; jump out if it's below a
        cmp     di, 'z'                  ; is it z?
        ja      slashprint               ; jump out if it's above z
        sub     di, 97                   ; convert the lower case letter to decimal
        mov     cl, [bx + di]            ; indexed addressing done here
        cmp     cl, -1                   ; is it -1?
        mov     [edi], cl                ; store the converted char in the string
        inc     esi                      ; point to the spot after
        inc     edi                      ; point to the next entry in the new string
        mov     [edi], byte 32           ; add a blank space in the new string where the lowercase letter was
        jmp     done                  

slashprint:
        cmp     di, '\'                  ; is it another slash?
        jne     errormsg                 ; jump and print an error message
        mov     [edi], byte 92           ; store a slash in the new string
        inc     edi                      ; move to the next position of the new string
        mov     [edi], byte 32           ; make the second char blank since both are slashes
        jmp     done                     ; return

errormsg:
        inc     esi                     ; skip over the character after the slash


done:
        ret

         ; end Subroutine.
```

Comment: Would help to add what type of assembly? x86 or x64, nasm, masm etc?

Comment: NASM / x86 is what we're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors in this code but I'll highlight those that can cause the crash:

- handle_ESC clobbers EDI so either it or main routine would then write to some random memory location
- I'm assuming this is 32-bit Linux application - using 16-bit registers for addressing is wrong

Comment: Yeah there's a lot I need to do to handle the different situations, I'm just trying to focus on one at a time. If I use the 32-bit registers, then won't I lost track of the size of the buffer and things like that? How do I prevent EDI from being clobbered? Just focusing on the lowercase label, what am I doing wrong? Even before I tried incrementing it inside the subroutine and things it was still crashing.

Comment: Always use 32-bit *address* registers in 32-bit application, it's that simple. Same goes for offsets - e.g. `[bx + di]` actually should be `[ebx + edi]`.
Regarding EDI - you need to track "lifetime" of the value inside the register through your program. If you want to use EDI as pointer to the output buffer then you cannot use same register for any other purpose (and if you really need to then you have to save it somewhere and then restore before using it for original purpose).
In this application I'd say just leave ESI and EDI for this single purpose and don't use it for anything else.

Comment: Also you don't use mappings array anywhere except in single place - so you can move ebx initialization with its address close to where you need to use it. This way you can reuse ebx register for other purposes elsewhere.
Also one thing I didn't noticed before - initialization of ebx seems wrong. You should've wrote `mov ebx, mappings` to get its address.

Comment: I'll bear all this in mind and fix this up then. Thanks very much!

Comment: Marked resolved because this helped me get the register usage sorted out. Thanks!